# Dangers of using keywords in method names

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, keyword

I understand that using keywords as variable names is not allowed. But something got me pondering about using keywords in method names.

I recently inherited an XCode project for an iOS app, where in *many* places I noticed the other coders had used keywords in method names such as:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*) appendData:(NSMutableDictionary*)incomingData for:(NSDictionary*)responseData
```

and

```
- (int) findCompensatedIndexOf:(id)searchQuery in:(NSArray*)floorData
```

In the mentioned methods, keywords `for` and `in` are used. Now, the app runs absolutely fine, both in the simulator, and on the devices, which means it works as it should. On the other hand, when using `CMD + Click` on the method name from a calling method in XCode, nothing happens. XCode jumps to the method in their relevant class if you CMD + Click on a method, but not here.

Now I understand that the app runs exactly as it should, but at the back of my mind, I am a little sceptical about this. After all, the OS and the IDE are, at the core, programs, and they *do* perceive something to be different.

Back to the point, what kind of dangers exactly does one face (in the present, or in the future) if they use keywords in method names? If it works now, does it mean it will work always, or a future update might conflict such methods?

**NOTE:** I am unsure whether this question belongs here in SO, or [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I request the moderators to decide that, and migrate if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Objective-C is a loosely documented language, I don't know if there is even an current official formal grammar and Apple's last edition of *The Objective-C Programming Language* is dated 2009 and out of date. Therefore all of what follows is a (slightly educated) guess.

There appears to be no restriction on using letter sequences which equate to keywords within a method name, and it would be unlikely. This is because the method name is the concatenation of its parts and the various parts are not standalone entities, e.g. your two examples are `appendData:for:` and `findCompensatedIndexOf:in:`, and there is no restriction on an identifier containing a subsequence of letters which match a keyword, e.g. `forest` is valid even though it contains `for`.

What you are seeing looks like "features" of the compiler, which various accepts keywords as method name parts and gets itself in a muddle. The CMD+Click doesn't work if a subpart is a keyword. For example, given the two methods:

```
- (void) anotherMethod:(int)x for:(int)z arg:(int)y;
- (void) anotherMethod:(int)x arg:(int)y;
```

Then CMD+Click on a call to the first method jumps to the second method... oops!

The syntax coloring is also messed up, but that is not too surprising.

My recommendation is to submit a bug report to Apple, at least that might illicit a formal response, and to avoid using keywords as method name parts - not because the code doesn't work but because Xcode gets muddled.

HTH

Comment: I ended up renaming the methods.
As for the bug report, well, I'm a procrastinator. :P

Answer (score 0):

There is something important you are missing: although you are using "for" and "in" in your method they are not THE method name, they are part of it, because in objective c the method name is the full name like findCompensatedIndexOf:in: and appendData:for: that is why in my understanding that the compiler is not showing an error with methods but shows with a variable, the total name is not a keyword.

So this will not be a problem for you now and it will not be in the future.